# Android, read-only config datatable

Tags: android, json, datatable

I have some data in datatable style that I need to load only for read (for example: game items parameters). What is the best way to organize it? Use SQL? On a desktop development I maked data in an excel table and converted it to JSON with this [tool](https://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/) for better speed optimization.

The table looks like this:

```
name stat1 stat2
item1 10 15
item2 5 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the amount of data is small and you plan on holding onto all of it in memory anyway, either:

- Hardcode it in Java, or
- Use JSON in `assets/` and read it in using `AssetManager` and your favorite JSON parser, or
- Use XML in `res/xml/` and read it in using `Resources`

If the amount of data is large, use [a SQLite database and `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).

Comment: Thanks. According [this article](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2016/04/19/mobile-performance-testing-json-vs-xml.aspx), JSON still better than XML but Android uses XML in native way. Maybe there are some optimizations on the compilation time, maybe because it's more readable for human.

Comment: @Psijic: If you have enough data that you are worried about the performance of JSON or XML, you should not be using JSON or XML for your scenario. You would be doing a one-time read of this information (per run of your app), not frequent I/O. If you are concerned about that one-time data load, don't load the data, but instead query a SQLite database as needed.